# In Yii2 framework, better place to define common function which is accessible everywhere like controller, model, view

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Like i want to create function with name "dt()"

```
function dt(){
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

and want to access it like this:-

```
echo dt(); //retrun current date and time format
```

Which is better place in Yii2 framework to do that?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0/ i hope its help for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it this way: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-helpers/

Create a folder `/common/helpers/`, then create a helper class there and add your static methods.

```
namespace common\helpers;

class DateHelper 
{
    public static function dt(){
        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

Usage

```
use common\helpers\DateHelper;

echo DateHelper::dt();
```

Answer (score 7):

For yii2, First Make a folder named `"components"` in your project root folder.

Then write your custom component inside components folder .i.e `MyComponent.php` or anything.

```
namespace app\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;

class MyComponent extends Component
{
  public function dt(){
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  }
}
```

Now add your component inside the config file.

```
'components' => [

         'mycomponent' => [

            'class' => 'app\components\MyComponent',

            ],
           ]
```

You are done!. Now you can use your component function "dt" inside any of your controller, model or view..

For example:

```
   Yii::$app->MyComponent->dt();
```

Comment: I would like to implement this solution.

Comment: For Me. This Is A Better Solution. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I use "common/components" folder. Here i create a file name "AppBasic.php" which will have functions which are for PHP and also Yii related functions.

some of the functions..

```
namespace common\components;

//Please make use of other classes you will use.
use yii\base\Exception;
use Yii;



/**
 * Class AppBasic Provides basic function to make programming EASY and FUN      things
 * Author : Jaimin MosLake
**/


class AppBasic
{


       /* 
       * I use this function to handle auto complete of password 
       * I put this in start of login page so chrome/ other browsers do not auto complete the username and password.
       */
    public static function renderAutoCompleteOff()
    {
            return ' 
            <input type="text" style="visibility: hidden;height:0px;" />
            <input type="password" style="visibility: hidden;height:0px;"  />';
    }

       /*
       *  My all time favorite checks whether it is array or not , if it is it returns value.   
       */ 
    public static function arrayKeyExist($key, $array , $returnValue = 1, $returnArray =  0)
    {
       if($returnValue)
       {
           return is_array($array) ?  array_key_exists($key , $array) ? $array[$key] : ( $returnArray ? [] : null )  : ( $returnArray ? [] : null ) ;
       }
       else
       {
           return is_array($array) ?  array_key_exists($key , $array) ? true : false : false ;
       }
    }


    public static function arrayNotEmpty( $array )
    {
        return is_array($array) ? !empty($array) ? true : false : false ;
    }

    public static function propertyExist($key, $object , $returnValue = 1)
    {
        if($returnValue)
        {
            return is_object($object) ?  property_exists($object , $key) ? $object->$key : null : null ;
        }
        else
        {
            return is_object($object) ?  property_exists($object , $key) ? 1 : 0 : 0 ;
        }
    }

    public static function isSquential($arr)
    {
        return  is_array($arr) ? array_keys($arr) === range(0, count($arr) - 1) : 0;
    }

    public static function makeItSquential($arr)
    {
        return (!empty($arr)) ? (self::isSquential($arr) ? $arr : [$arr]) : [] ;
    }

    public static function stringNotNull($string)
    {
        return ($string != "" && $string != null);
    }

    public static function giveDetail($data)
    {
        return (is_object($data) ? "OBJECT" : (is_array($data) ?  (AppBasic::isSquential($data) ? "SEQUENTIAL_ARRAY" :  "ASSOCIATIVE_ARRAY" )  : "STRING" )) ;
    }


     public static function printR($data, $exit = 1)
    {
        echo "<pre></br>";
        print_r($data);
        if ($exit == '1') {
            exit;
        }

        echo "</pre></br>";
    }

    public static function printRT($data, $title = null , $exit = 0)
    {
         AppBasic::printR($title." START ", 0);
         AppBasic::printR($data, 0 );
         AppBasic::printR($title." END ", $exit);
    }


    public static function test($exit = 0 , $file = __FILE__, $class = __CLASS__ , $function = __FUNCTION__, $line = __LINE__ )
    {
        self::printR(" FILE : ".$file." <br/> CLASS : ".$class." <BR/> FUNCTION : ".$function." <BR/> LINE : ".$line, $exit);
    }

    public static function printReturn($data, $status = 1)
    {
        $html = "" ;
        $html .= "<pre></br>";
        $html .=  print_r($data , true );
        $html .= "</pre></br>";

        return $html ;
    }

    public static function getErrorArray($msg, $errors)
    {

        foreach ($errors as $k => $value)
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($value); $i++)
            {
                $msg[sizeof($msg)] = $value[$i];
            }
        }

        return $msg;
    }

    public static function getErrorArrayStraight($msg, $errors)
    {

        foreach ($msg as $k => $value) {
            $p = array_key_exists($k, $errors) ? sizeof($errors[$k]) : 0;
            $errors[$k][$p] = $value;
        }

        return $errors;
    }

    public static function getFinalError($array1, $array2)
    {
        $error = Helpers::getErrorArrayStraight($array1, $array2);
        $message = Helpers::getErrorMessageStraight($error);

        return $message;
    }

    public static function getErrorMessageStraight($errors)
    {

        $html = "";
        $html .= "<p>Please solve the following errors</p>";
        $html .= "<ul>";
        foreach ($errors as $k => $value) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($value); $i++) {
                $html .= "<li>";
                $html .= $value[$i];
                $html .= "</li>";
            }
        }
        $html .= "</ul>";

        return $html;
    }

    public static function getErrorMessage($type, $msg)
    {
        $html = "";
        if ($type == "failed") {
            $html .= '<div class="whistleblower" >--__FAILED__--</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="errors"><ul id="errors">';
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($msg); $i++) {
                $html .= '<li>' . $msg[$i] . '</li>';
            }
            $html .= '</ul></div>';
        } else {
            $html .= '<div class="whistleblower" >--__SUCCESS__--</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="errors"><ul id="errors">';
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($msg); $i++) {
                $html .= '<li>' . $msg[$i] . '</li>';
            }
            $html .= '</ul></div>';
        }
        return $html;
    }

    public static function getUrlInfo($name , $operator = "/")
    {
        $controllerName = \Yii::$app->controller->id ;
        $controllerName = strtolower($controllerName) ;
        $actionName =  \Yii::$app->controller->action->id ;
        $actionName = strtolower($actionName) ;
        $combination = $controllerName.$operator.$actionName ;

        return $$name ;
    }

    public static function date_convert($dt, $tz1, $df1 = "Y-m-d H:i:s", $tz2 = "UTC", $df2 = "Y-m-d H:i:s")
    {
        $returnVal = null ;
        if($dt != null || $dt != "")
        {
            if($tz1 == null || $tz1 == "")
            {
                $tz1 = date_default_timezone_get();
            }

            if($tz2 == null || $tz2 == "")
            {
                $tz2 = "UTC";
            }

            $timeZoneObj = new DateTimeZone($tz1);
            //create DateTime object
            $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($df1, $dt, $timeZoneObj );
            //convert timezone
            if(is_object($d))
            {

                $timeZoneObj2 = new DateTimeZone($tz2);

                try
                {
                    $d->setTimeZone($timeZoneObj2);
                }
                catch(Exception $e)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Date can not be formatted");    
                }



            }
            //convert dateformat
            $returnVal = is_object($d) ? $d->format($df2) : null  ;
        }

        return  $returnVal ;
    }

    public static function checkValidations($model, $exit = 1)
    {

        self::printR('Attribute', 0);
        self::printR($model->scenario, 0);

        self::printR('Attribute', 0);
        self::printR($model->attributes, 0);

        self::printR('Validate', 0);
        self::printR($model->validate(), 0);

        self::printR('Errors', 0);
        self::printR($model->getErrors(), 0);

        //self::printR('Model', 0);
        //self::printR($model, 0);

        if ($exit) {
            exit;
        }

    }

    public static function setTimeZoneByTimezone($tz)
    {
        if($tz != null && $tz != "")
        {

            //Helpers::printR($tz );
            ini_set('date.timezone', $tz);
            //echo date_default_timezone_get();
            //exit;
        }
    }

        public static function generateRandomString($length = 10)
    {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }

    public static function getExtention($filename)
    {
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        return $ext;
    }

    public static function createDirectoryStructureFromBasePath($structure)
    {
        $url = Yii::app()->basePath;
        $explode = explode("/", $structure);
        //self::printR($explode , 0 );

        foreach($explode as $k=>$val)
        {
            if($val == "..")
            {
                $dir = $url."/".$val;
                if(file_exists($dir) && is_dir($dir))
                {
                    $url = $dir ;
                }
                else
                {
                    $url = $url ;
                }
            }
            else if($val != "")
            {
                $dir = $url.'/'.$val;
                if (!file_exists($dir) && !is_dir($dir)) {
                    mkdir($dir);
                }

                $url = $dir ;
            }
        }


        return $url."/" ;
        //self::printR($url);
        //$file = $dir."/".$fileNameShould;
     }

}
```

I also do the same for controllers. I extend them by the Backendcontroller and FrontendController . They were extended by MosLakeController [My Name] and it is extended by controller.

So i put all access control thing into frontend and backend controller.  I also have functions in MosLakeController.

```
public function handleRender($view , $params = [] , $jsonBasedRender =  0 , $jsonBasedRenderOptions = [] , $returnHtml = 0 , $renderPartial = 0 )
{
    if(\Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
    {
        if($returnHtml)
        {
            return $this->renderPartial($view , $params);
        }
        else if($jsonBasedRender)
        {
            $html = $this->renderPartial($view , $params);
            $jsonBasedRenderOptions['html'] =   $html ;
            $jsonBasedRenderOptions['status'] = 1 ;
            $jsonBasedRenderOptions['action'] =  isset($jsonBasedRenderOptions['action']) ?  $jsonBasedRenderOptions['action'] : "RENDER" ;
            $jsonBasedRenderOptions['message'] = isset($jsonBasedRenderOptions['message']) ?  $jsonBasedRenderOptions['message'] : "" ;

            echo json_encode($jsonBasedRenderOptions);
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->renderPartial($view , $params);
        }
    }
    else if($renderPartial)
    {
        return $this->renderPartial($view, $params);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->render($view, $params);
    }
}

public function findModelByPk($modelName ,  $primaryKey, $strict = 1)
{
   $model = new $modelName();
   if($primaryKey != '')
   {
       $model = $model->findOne($primaryKey);
   }

    if($model == null && $strict == 1)
    {
        throw new Exception('Required data is not exist.');
    }

    return $model;
}

public function findModelByAttributes($modelName, $condition, $params, $strict = 1, $one = 1)
{
    $model = new $modelName();
    if($one)
    {
        $model = $model->find()->where($condition , $params )->one();

        if($model == null && $strict == 1)
        {
            throw new HttpException('Required data is not exist for '.$modelName.'.');
        }
        else if($model == null)
        {
            $model = new $modelName();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $model = $model->find()->where($condition , $params )->all();

        if(empty($model) && $strict == 1)
        {
            throw new HttpException('Required data is not exist for '.$modelName.'.');
        }
        else if(empty($model))
        {
            $model = [new $modelName()];
        }

    }



    return $model;
}
```

And i also do the same for models. I extend all the ActiveMdels and ALso Models [ Without DB connection] and when theyhave any error afterValidate then i insert data in Database about the error trace with Yii::error() or Yii::info() or Yii::warning().

I do many things to make coding easy and fun and keep learning new things..!!!

Answer (score -1):

It's not a good approach, but if you insists on having function instead of static class, you can put the method definition in `bootstrap.php`.

Usually what I put in bootstrap.php other than defining alias is configuring compability, e.g in fastcgi there is no `getallheaders`, hence I define it there.